# iOS Pan Gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to instead of making my pan gesture spam the function when it pans, that it only plays the function once when the panning is finished, I have looked all online and fail to find a way to do this. Anyone got any solutions?

Current code below:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self  action:@selector(didPan:)];
self.mapView.gestureRecognizers = @[panRecognizer];

- (void) didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"DID PAN");
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @tdevoy I think he is saying that the function is called multiple times when the pan gesture is being made, but he only wants it called when the panning is done.

Comment: Right now while panning the log is spammed with the "did pan" message. Instead I would rather "did pan" was just placed in the log once after I complete the pan gesture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void)panGestureDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)panGesture {

    if(panGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try that now. Thank you! Can't accept your answer for 6 mins.

Comment: thanks! Worked great was trying to find out a solution to my problem for days and this was a great work around I found. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

ViewController.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *img;

ViewController.m

viewDidLoad

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];

[_img addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

Comment: - (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = self.img.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;
    imageViewPosition.y += translation.y;
    
   _img.center = imageViewPosition;
    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}